# How to read data from external properties file using jar: Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

The spring-boot application I developed needs to run as a jar file, but the properties file needs to be read from outside the jar file.
If I run the jar file with arguments and `--spring.config.location=client.properties` the arguments are not passed into the jar file but the application can read the properties file.

```
java -jar application.jar product version mode
```

This would print the product, version, and mode but would throw a bean error since it's missing the properties file but.

```
java -jar application.jar product version mode --spring.config.location=client.properties
```

This throws the error `missing product version and mode`

How can I run a jar file that should read the properties file from a specified location with arguments passed to it?

Comment: `client.properties` isn't really a valid location. Either prefix with `file:` or `classpath:` to indicate where it needs to be read from. Also you should propably use `spring.config.additional-location` instead. Finally instead of specifying the specific properties file just rename it to `application.properties` and place it next to your `application.jar` and Spring Boot will automatically load it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass arguments as well as property file like this

```
java -jar application.jar -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--argument1=value1 --argument2=value2" --spring.config.location=client.properties
```